# BLAS-LAPACK-ATLAS-R installation with multithreading?

Tags: r, gcc, atlas

I am trying to setup ATLAS, BLAS, LAPACK, and R on an OpenSuSE 12.2 server with an 8 core AMD athlon FX-8320. I have turned off the CPU frequency scaling using cpufreq and a script cfu from paste.opensuse.org/92162247 made by James McDaniel.

So following the instructions, here http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node45.html I didn't need to install gcc (that I know yet) I have gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.1 20120723 installed, g++, and gfortran the same version as gcc.

The instructions are to make a bogus configuration of ATLAS to determine the compiler flags to use. ATLAS is configured in the instructions as '../configure -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=2200 -Fa alg -fPIC'. I modify this to what I think will work for my setup ' ../configure -b 64 -t 8 -Fa alg -fpic -A x86_64 -D c -DpentiumCPS=3500 -Si latune 1 --prefix=/usr/local/lib64 --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/opt/maths/lapack-3.4.2.tgz' I get these errors.

```
OS configured as Linux (1)

Assembly configured as GAS_x8664 (2)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  AVXMAC (3,504)
ERROR: enum fam=6, chip=8, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2
/bin/sh: line 1: 13849 Segmentation fault      ./xarchinfo_linux -a > config0.out
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 139
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_linux] Error 2

Architecture configured as  UNKNOWNx86 (35)
ERROR: enum fam=6, chip=8, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2

Clock rate configured as 3500Mhz
Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 8'
ERROR: enum fam=6, chip=8, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2
Cannot detect CPU throttling.
```

Atlas makes a Make.inc and if I fgrep F77 and F77 flags I get 'gfortran-4.7' AND '-O -mavx -fpic -m64'. Maybe the -mavx flag handles the AVXMAC error? Do I need -mavx? I will proceed with my instructions...

Comment: There are alternative to Atlas; you could for example try OpenBLAS.

Comment: Thanks Dirk!  I read your comparison paper. In the paper you used Ubuntu package manager synaptic to install libatlas3gf. I am using OpenSUSE 12.2 and haven't located libatlas3gf yet. Have you compiled ATLAS with pthreads manually?  I think maybe i've been fooled abit thinking that taking 9 hours to 'make build' and all of the stdout, stderr, and 'tuning' will result in less errors or a faster BLAS. I will look into OpenBLAS. I am wondering if I can install with OpenMP now.

Comment: No, in Debian/Ubuntu you get a pretty easy choice between BLAS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a real answer, but difficult to read as a comment):

A few more considerations on Dirk's recommendation to use OpenBLAS.

I also use OpenBLAS (on Ubuntu and CentOS systems).

- One consideration that is important for me on the 8 and 12 core machines is that OpenBLAS allows *dynamic* setting of the number of threads to use, which [ATLAS doesn't](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tnum). In Order to set the number of threads dynamicall from within R, I use [Simon Fuller's OpenBLASThreads](https://github.com/simonfullernuim/OpenBlasThreads).
- OpenBLAS was pretty straightforward to build on both systems.
- Binary .deb packages are available, but last time I checked them, they had the maximum possible number of threads set to 2. [However, this is going to change](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openblas/+bug/817212). Till now, I also build the library from source on Ubuntu machines with > 2 cores.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I went for the openblas and I am trying to work out some bugs. Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868191/openblas-openmp-and-r-is-there-a-decent-test